# And it was so? Perhaps mistranslated?

Tags: hebrew, grammar-dikduk, parashat-bereishit

A speaker of modern Hebrew would translate the following expression from Genesis 1:

> וַיְהִי-כֵן

"And it will be so."

But every translation of Torah I have seen says "and it was so."

Couldn't it be translated as G-d saying "and it will be so"? After all, quotes in Torah text aren't indicated, so the translator wouldn't know where the beginning and end of a quote really should be.

But I have heard also that Torah uses future tense to describe past tense. Are there other, clearer examples of this without the alternate meaning?

Comment: It means "and it was so". Why would it not mean that? This is standard biblical Hebrew.

Comment: Actually, in modern Hebrew it would be וִיהִי כֵן with a _hirik_ under the _vav_.

Comment: @Ypnypn In biblical Hebrew too, eg. ויהי נועם...

Answer (score 9):

[See here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/2720/21) for more.

Biblical Hebrew employs a rule called the "vav ha-hipuch." The preceding "v'" flips the tense from past to future, or vice versa.

Thus "yehi chen", it will be so; "vayhi chen", it was so.

"Amar Paroh", Pharaoh said; "v'amar Paroh livnei yisrael" -- Pharoh *will say* regarding the Jews.

"Moshe yedaber", Moses would speak. "Vaydaber Moshe" -- Moshe spoke.

"V'heshiv et hagzela", he will return the stolen item ...

Comment: "יהי כן" is in jussive, meaning "let it be so".  The translation of "it will be so" is "יהיה כן".

Comment: Note not all vav's change the tense. Just [four] (three) weeks ago we had ואכלתי חטאת היום and on Pesach we had וישבו המים where the tense doesn't change.

Comment: @DoubleAA "VEyashuvu hamayim" -- the waters shall return. "VAyashuvu hamayim" -- the waters returned. No? "VeAchalti Chatas" is a weird one as it's a hypothetical bridging the simple-past "hikrivu" with the simple-future "hayitav." Sforno's reading has the whole phrase preceded by a "hen", notifying us that this is all a thought experiment, so we know from context it's not the future tense: "suppose that they sacrificed ... and then I ate -- would that be good?"

Comment: @Shalom Yes those are the examples to which I referred. The response to Moshe is indeed hard to parse, but the grammar of that phrase isn't weird at all. It's standard past tense. Consider like it Hoshea 12:11

Comment: Couldn't it be as Conway said - "let it be so"?

Comment: @GregoryMagarshak no, context doesn't bear that out. The book of Esther opens with "Vayhi" -- "it happened in the days of ..."